# How to fast find element in sorted Vector?

Tags: java, search, vector, binary-search

Java class `java.util.Vector` has a `.sort(Comparator)` method, but no `.search(key,Comparator)` or `.binarySearch(key,Comparator)` .

Answer (score 1):

`Vector` implements `List`, so you can use [`Collections.binarySearch(List, T, Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-java.util.Comparator-)

```
final Vector<String> vector = new Vector<>();
vector.add("foo");
vector.add("bar");
vector.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
int fooIndex = Collections.binarySearch(vector, "foo", Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Since the vector in this example uses *natural ordering*, we can also use a simpler overload

```
// ...
int fooIndex = Collections.binarySearch(vector, "foo");
```

Comment: It's easier to use [`Collections.binarySearch(List, T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-) if the list is arranged by natural ordering.

Comment: @AndyTurner I added it.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented a binary search method (algorithm from: [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binäre_Suche](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin%C3%A4re_Suche) ):

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> int vec_binSearch(final Vector<T> vec_elements,
                    final T key, final Comparator<T> comp) {
        final int method = 2;
        final int NOT_SET_int = -1, COMPARE_IDENTICAL = 0;
        int index;

        if ((vec_elements == null) || (key == null) || (comp == null))
            throw (new NullPointerException(
                            "Unable to search in 'null' list a 'null' element by 'null' comparator."));
        // else: ok, continue.
        if (vec_elements.size() == 0) return -1;
        // else: non-empty list, search.

        switch (method) {
            case 1: {
                final T[] ar_T = (T[]) (vec_elements.toArray());
                index = Arrays.binarySearch(ar_T, key, comp);
            }
                break;
            case 2: {
                // Algorithm see: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binäre_Suche
                int links = 0;
                int rechts = vec_elements.size() - 1;
                int mitte;
                T midElem;
                int cmpResult;
                //
                index = NOT_SET_int;
                while (links <= rechts) {
                    mitte = links + ((rechts - links) / 2);
                    midElem = vec_elements.elementAt(mitte);
                    cmpResult = comp.compare(midElem, key);
                    if (cmpResult == COMPARE_IDENTICAL) {
                        // Element key gefunden!
                        index = mitte;
                        break; // exit while-loop
                    } else {
                        if (cmpResult > 0) {
                            // im linken Abschnitt weitersuchen
                            rechts = mitte - 1;
                        } else {
                            // midElem < key
                            // im rechten Abschnitt weitersuchen
                            links = mitte + 1;
                        } // end if
                    } // end if
                } // end while

                if (index == NOT_SET_int) {
                    if (rechts < 0)
                        index = rechts;
                    else
                        index = -rechts - 2;
                    // end if
                } // else: found, return index.
            }
                break;
            default:
                throw (new IllegalStateException(
                                "binary search method not implemented"));
        }

        return index;
    }
```